# Verify compatibility versions of solr/postgresql database with Spring boot 1.5.9

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Where I can check the compatibility versions of solr and postgresql database with Spring boot 1.5.9?

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/93?closed=1) I seen upgrade to Solr 5.5.5 that means this is the last version of solr compatible with Spring boot 1.5.9? But about postgresql, when I can find this information?

Answer (score 0):

I found the list with dependency versions [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).